# Unable to pass dynamic xpath in repository file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, visualstudio, properties-file

My code is :

```
for (int z = 0; z < rows.size(); z++) {

rows.get(z).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ng-scope'][" + (z + 1) + "]//*[@placeholder='Stop Name']")).sendKeys(shuttleObj.getStopArea());

}
```

And I want to use repository to pass xpath. I want this value multiple times for every rows in a table but if I am taking properties like

```
for (int z = 0; z < rows.size(); z++) {

rows.get(z).findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("path[" + (z + 1) + "]area")).sendKeys(shuttleObj.getStopArea()));

}

path=//*[@class='ng-scope']
area=//*[@placeholder='Stop Name']
```

This code is not working. If I am taking total elements like

```
path=//*[@class='ng-scope'][" + (z + 1) + "]//*[@placeholder='Stop Name']
```

It can be able to run but in same row. But I want this value in every rows in a table.

Comment: use this - `props.getProperty(path+ "[" +(Z+1)+ "]" + value)`

Comment: sorry my bad just replace `value` by your `area` variable name.

Comment: i'm not bale to understand that what you want to do, but why are u using `"` stiil before `path` variable and after `area` variable these are your simple variable with string values which you want to use.

Comment: why are you not directly using this - `props.getProperty(path+ "[" +(Z+1)+ "]" + area)`

Comment: because path and area are not an elements, these are xpath which i am using in my code like e.g path= //*[@class='ng-scope'] and area=//*[@placeholder='Stop Name'] . I am combining these two xpath and using as one xpath in my code like e.g 
rows.get(z).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ng-scope'][" + (z + 1) + "]//*[@placeholder='Stop Name']")).sendKeys(shuttleObj.getStopArea());

But I have to use this xpath in  below code by using props.getProperty.

rows.get(z).findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("path[" + (z + 1) + "]area")).sendKeys(shuttleObj.getStopArea()));

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you-
**Your property file-(db.properties)**

```
path=//*[@class='ng-scope'] 
area=//*[@placeholder='Stop Name']
```

**Now in your java class-**

```
String pathValue= props.getProperty("path");
String areaValue= props.getProperty("area");

for (int z = 0; z < rows.size(); z++) 
{
rows.get(z).findElement(By.xpath(pathValue+"[" + (z + 1) + "]"+areaValue)).sendKeys(shuttleObj.getStopArea());

}
```

*Note:-* Here if your variable `rows` is also from properties file then with same above way use this.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome!, please if it's your answer then accept it.

Comment: @Samira it's your different question please post it as a new question so that everyone can help you.